# Passing array as arguments in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, arguments

I have two methods:

```
static m1(...args: any[]) {
    //using args as array ...
}

static m2(str: string, ...args: any[]){
    //do something
    //....

    //call to m1
    m1(args);
}
```

The call to `m1(1,2,3)` works as expect. However, the call `m2("abc",1,2,3)` will pass to `m1([1,2,3])`, not as expect: `m1(1,2,3)`.

So, how to pass `args` as arguments when make call to `m1` in `m2`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
T.m1.apply(this, args);
```

Where T is the enclosing class of `m1`.

Comment: Yes, passing `this` in this case will make `this` within `m1` refer to object of outer context (`m2`). Still need a way to refer to `this` of `m1` within `m1`.

Comment: I'm using 0.9.5, but my sample is incorrect. Actually, my code is A.m1() and B.m2(), so I fixed by call m1.apply(A,args), and it works great. Thank you again!

Comment: Not use this method. It's javascript, not typescript. Use the response by Rick Live :)

Answer (score 141):

Actually, using the `...` again when calling the method will work.

It generates the apply call for you in javascript.

```
static m1(...args: any[]) {
    //using args as array ...
}

static m2(str: string, ...args: any[]){
    //do something
    //....

    //call to m1

    // m1(args);
    // BECOMES
    m1(...args);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this probably didn't work when the question was first asked. But this is the best way now.