# How to call var-args member function with array of params?

Tags: typescript, variadic-functions

Consider this:

```
class A
{
    fa(...args: any[])
    {
        //args always has length of one
        //and the first value in args is an array
    }
}

var a = new A();
class B
{
    f1(...args: any[])
    {
       args.unshift('something');
       a.fa.apply(args);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, because fa() is not a static function. This example solves the problem for the case where fa() is static: [Passing array as arguments in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443101/passing-array-as-arguments-in-typescript)

But how can I do an 'apply' on fa when it is a member function?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `apply` is `this`, so just use `a`.

Fixed your `a.fa.apply`:

```
class A
{
    fa(...args: any[])
    {
        console.log(args.length == 3); // true
        console.log(args);
    }
}
var a = new A();

class B
{
    fb(...args: any[])
    {
       args.unshift('second');
       a.fa.apply(a,args);
    }
}
var b = new B();
b.fb('first','second');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But one thing I was missing that I don't have in my example, is that when you call apply you can _only_ have 2 args, thisArg, and args. So if you have additional args you want to add, you have to unshift them into args. This is they key I was missing.